# How can I restore the Excel drag-and-drop square file handle without closing and reopening Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2013

When I open my Excel 2013 document, and select a block of cells, I see a small square drag handle with which I can drag and copy that block of cells. After I do this a couple times, the handle is no longer evident. Then I have to close and re-open my document in order for the drag handle to reappear. I have checked to make sure the 'options > advanced > [X] Enable fill handle and cell drag-and-drop' check box is still checked, and it is. I have tried unchecking the box and rechecking it, to no avail. I have also checked this problem by opening my document on multiple computers with multiple Excel versions on different worksheets, and the behavior is the same. So there may be something wrong with my document. My document is rather large (17M) and when I have a lot of dragging and copying to do, it gets quite tiresome.

Does anyone know how to restore the small square drag handle which appears when a block of cells is selected, without closing and reopening the Excel document? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot about your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This problem used to happen to me frequently with Excel 2010, and at the same time seemed to disable the right-click options within the worksheet, are you still able to right-click and see the Cut/Copy/Paste etc options?

I'm afraid I have no idea why it happens, but this is the solution I used to use which seemed to work (you can also put the line of code in a macro and link it to a button in the file if the problem happens frequently):

Press Alt + F11 to open the VB window.
Next press Ctrl + G, and type in (or copy & paste):

Application.CommandBars("Cell").Reset

Then press the Enter key.
Press Alt+Q to return to the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

This article on [repairmsexcel](http://www.repairmsexcel.com/blog/resolve-excel-fill-handle-not-working-issue) provides a number of potential solutions to this unfortunate problem. The primary solutions to try include:

- Removing filters
- Check automatic calculation is on
- Press F4 (repeat command) repeatedly

I expect that you will find that column filtering is the root cause and turning this off will fix the issue.

I hope that this helps and please let us know which solution works for you.